# viewer.js triggers addEventListener resize at tab switch in IE 11 causing error and crashes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf.js

In chrome I got the follow scenario working:

I have a webpage with multiple tabs inside it and one of them includes showing pdfs using pdfjs.

When I run chrome everything is fine.

In IE11 I have the following issue.
When I looked at the pdf tab and load another tab I get an exception at the following code lines in the viewer.js

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function webViewerResize(evt) {
if (PDFViewerApplication.initialized) { //here it causes the exception 
var currentScaleValue = PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentScaleValue;
if (currentScaleValue === 'auto' ||
    currentScaleValue === 'page-fit' ||
    currentScaleValue === 'page-width') {
  // Note: the scale is constant for 'page-actual'.
  PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = currentScaleValue;
} else if (!currentScaleValue) {
  // Normally this shouldn't happen, but if the scale wasn't initialized
  // we set it to the default value in order to prevent any issues.
  // (E.g. the document being rendered with the wrong scale on load.)
  PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = DEFAULT_SCALE_VALUE;
}
PDFViewerApplication.pdfViewer.update();
}

 // Set the 'max-height' CSS property of the secondary toolbar.
    SecondaryToolbar.setMaxHeight(document.getElementById('viewerContainer'));
});
```

The exception is

Unhandled exception at line 7548, column 3 in http:/.../pdfjs/web/viewer.js
0x800a138f - Laufzeitfehler in JavaScript: Die Eigenschaft "initialized" eines undefinierten oder Nullverweises kann nicht abgerufen werden. occurred

So as far as I understand loading another tab in IE11 it calls for 'resize', which chrome doesn't do.

The question is how can I make IE11 not trigger this EventListener or tell it at tabselect that there is no pdf and no pdfjs must be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to enter the old tabcontent via tabstrip-content.empty before loading a new one.